# Chrome console handling jQuery $(this) bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console, this

It is kind of strange.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>feng</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('table tr').click(function(e){
   console.log($(this)==null); //returns False
});
```

The Chrome console outputs `False`, which is expected.
However, when I toggle a break point in the function and trigger the event, I found that ,if I type `$(this)` in the Chrome **console**, it returns `null`

Comment: Where are you triggering the breakpoint?

Comment: in the `console.log($(this)==null);` line

Answer (score 4):

The `this` "variable" isn't really a variable.  I don't think Chrome establishes a value for `this` to match that in the current execution context; it'd be pretty hard to do that, frankly.

If you want to be able to debug such a function, just make sure you put the `this` value into a regular old local variable:

```
   var saveThis = this;
```

Then, `$(saveThis)` should work for you.

Comment: I type:this
The console returns:<tr class>​…​</tr>​

Comment: sorry, typed Enter by accident.

Comment: I type:_this_ in the console. The console returns:_<tr class>​…​</tr>​_. So this turns out to be an defined variable. And when I do as you advised, var saveThis = this, the console returns undefined. I am confused and this is what actually happened

Comment: Well I confess that I'm not a Chrome console expert, but it sounds like you're expecting that the console's execution environment will match the current executing/debugged code. That may not be true at all.

Answer (score 2):

I usually find it handy to save "this" when I plan to pass it to another function.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: I typically use `$self` instead to avoid confusion. The variable might be available in contexts where `this` no longer refers to the same thing.